# JSFiddle does not run my AngularJS code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea, jsfiddle, angularjs-ng-click

After typing inside `textarea` and clicking on a `button`, I want to remove text inside `textarea` using `AngularJS`.
Please refer to following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aman2690/2Ljrp54q/10/

Still getting

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available!
```

Even after setting `ng-model` to `''` , `textarea` does not clean up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your plunker `No wrap - in <body>` and add `<body ng-app="MyApp">` to `Fiddle Options`.

Here is an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ljrp54q/23/)

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is fine. Your JSFiddle isn't. Set the framework options to `No Wrap - in <head>`.

Answer (score 0):

need to use $scope in controller $scope acts as a model. Check the link below

http://plnkr.co/edit/TpGfbDOtxvrC6FwhpbT8?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.clicked = function () {
      console.log("here");
        $scope.message = '';
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied and pasted your code off JSFiddle into a local HTML file as the JSFiddle was giving console errors, and the code works as expected.